# Vista hibernation doesn't work properly (PC turns on just after hibernation)

Tags: windows-vista, hibernate

I have a VISAT business that I configured its power setting to hibernate and the hibernation seems ok (see later why I am thinking in this way).
The problem is that after the Windows went into hibernation, the PC boot up and restart again. The events are as follow:
1-After I select Hibernation, the Windows start to hibernate and save the environment into hard drive.
2- PC seems to turn off.
3- PC turns on again and resumes Windows and the window comes out of hibernation.
4- If after step 2, I turn PC manually (during boot up as soon the POST screen appears), the PC turns off and I can return to my PC at a later time.

I googled about the problem and tried to find any reason for turning on the PC after hibernation but none of the suggested solutions worked. Can you suggest any reason for this?

Please note that the Windows shutdown correctly (turn off after shutdown).

Comment: I have a similar problem with my Dell workstation (Windows 7). It is the same if I try to make it sleep. After a few minutes it restarts again. I have never figured out why.

Answer (score 1):

See if you have any BIOS updates available or check the settings in the BIOS as it is possible that advanced power settings are set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I checked all options in BIOS and set them to default. No change.
It was working at one point and hence I don't think there is any need for BIOS upgrade but I am happy to upgrade it is I know how I can find a suitable upgrade for it. Is there any documentation about how to upgrade a PC BIOS?